# Where to store information about country state and city in a website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, frontend

I'm using ReactJS and Google App Engine to make a website where you can register land parcels.

In the registration page there are 3 dropdowns (like in the picture): Country, State and City, where the choice in one of those dropdowns affects the options in the next one.

I have an excel file with all the information about these Countries/States/Cities organized in a tree-like structure where i can check the relationship between them.

I was wondering how I should store the information (excel/map) and where I should store it.

Should I save the Country list on the front-end and the rest on the back-end database and request the states and cities as needed?

Would it be a better idea to store everything on the front-end? or in the back end and request everything everytime?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can either store the data in a const variable, inside of a React component, and then call the component in a seperate component with your drop down menu. Or, if the data is constantly changing and being updated, you can setup a firebase realtime database (easiest), or use another database option, and pull the information with an api with specific key value pairs set to each city option. So depending on the city selected, the api will pull the required information from your database, and update the variable.

To display the data underneath the drop-down-menu, I use the following code(similar) to update the displayed data.

```
export default function cityGrid() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('Los Angeles');

  const [LosAngelesContentVisible, setLosAngelesContentVisible] = useState(false);
  const [otherCityContentVisible, setOtherCityContentVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    city === 'Los Angeles' ? setLosAngelesContentVisible(true) : setLosAnglesContentVisible(false)
    city === 'othercity1' ? setOtherCityContentVisible(true) : setOtherCityContentVisible(false)
   ...etc
}

const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  setCity(e.target.value)
}
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="Los Angeles" onClick={handleOnChange}/>
        <option value="othercity1" onClick={handleOnChange}/>
        <option value="othercity2" onClick={handleOnChange}/>
        <option value="othercity3" onClick={handleOnChange}/>
      <select>
    </div>
    <div>
      {LosAngelesContentVisible &&
        <div>
          <ReactComponentWithApiData city={"Los Angeles"} />
        </div>
      }
      {othercityContentVisible &&
        <div>
          <ReactComponentWithApiData city={"othercity1"} />
        </div>
      }
      ...etc
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

You will need to alter the code obviously, didn't fill everything in for you, but this should be the main premise to use. I am currently using this in a real estate website I made that uses the individual react components with "city='random-city-name'" to update the information gathered from the api in that component.

I am using a button in place of the select & option components that I put into the code above, and you might need to play with that to get the same result. Hopefully this helps you.

If you need the code I used to pull the data from my realtime database, let me know and I will post that for you as well.